# Facebook android app keeps crashing even though there are no errors in my code. Why?

Tags: android, facebook

If you import the facebook SDK library, the code works (ignore the deprecated methods for now lol) and there are no errors or warnings.

However, when I run my facebook app on my Android 2.2 or 4.2 emulator, the app crashes either upon opening or after the log on screen. Why?

Is it because I'm not implementing Async Task? If so, how does that work?

Here's my code:

```
package com.sara.facebookappl;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;
import com.facebook.android.Util;

public  class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, DialogListener {

    Facebook fb; 
    ImageView button; 
    SharedPreferences sp; 
    TextView welcome; 
    Button post; 

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            post=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

            String APP_ID = getString(R.string.APP_ID);
            fb= new Facebook(APP_ID);

            sp =getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            String access_token=sp.getString("access_token", null);
            long expires=sp.getLong("access_expires", 0);

            if (access_token !=null) {
                    fb.setAccessToken(access_token);
            }
            if(expires !=0) {
                    fb.setAccessExpires(expires);
            }


            button=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.login);
            button.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
            updateButtonImage();

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void updateButtonImage() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            post.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.com_facebook_loginbutton_blue);
            //logout button

            if (fb.isSessionValid()) {
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.com_facebook_loginbutton_blue);
                    // ^logout button

            JSONObject obj=null;
            URL img_url =null;

            try {
            String jsonUser= fb.request("me");
            obj = Util.parseJson(jsonUser);
            String id=obj.optString("id"); 
            String name = obj.optString("name");
            welcome.setText("Welcome, " + name);
            }catch(FacebookError e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

            }catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

            }else {
                    post.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.com_facebook_loginbutton_blue);
            }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void buttonClicks(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.button1:
                            //post

                            Bundle params= new Bundle();

                            params.putString("name", "User X"); 
                            params.putString("caption", "Rating"); 
                            params.putString("description", "User X Rated"); 
                            params.putString("link", "http://..."); 



                            fb.dialog(MainActivity.this, "feed", params, new Facebook.DialogListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onError(DialogError e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancel() {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                    }
                            });
                            break;
            }
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void onClick(View v) {
            if(fb.isSessionValid()) {

                    try {
                    fb.logout(getApplicationContext());
                    updateButtonImage();
                    //button will close our our session
            }catch(MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }else{
                    //login into facebook
                    fb.authorize(MainActivity.this, new String[] {"email"}, new Facebook.DialogListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "fbError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(DialogError e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    Editor editor=sp.edit();
                                    editor.putString("access_token", fb.getAccessToken());
                                    editor.putLong("access_expires", fb.getAccessExpires());
                                    editor.commit();
                                    updateButtonImage();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancel() {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onCancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                    });

                    }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
            return true;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            fb.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(DialogError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

LogCat Errors:

```
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sara.facebookappl/com.sara.facebookappl.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180) 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039) 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117) 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385) 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236) 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214) 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70) 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50) 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340) 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87) 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128) 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316) 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:461) 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433) 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290) 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240) 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:282) 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177) 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:271) 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:219) 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): at com.facebook.android.Facebook.requestImpl(Facebook.java:806) 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:732) 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): at com.sara.facebookappl.MainActivity.updateButtonImage(MainActivity.java:83) 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): at com.sara.facebookappl.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:63) 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080) 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144) 
12-16 04:56:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(822): ... 11 more 
12-16 04:56:59.090: D/dalvikvm(822): GC_CONCURRENT freed 150K, 9% free 2723K/2988K, paused 7ms+58ms, total 239ms
```

Comment: Post your LogCat errors. Understand that there is a difference between compile-time and run-time errors, the compiler cannot warn you about every error that may exist...

Comment: Sorry. Check above. And I apologize in advance about the font size... Not sure how it got that big.

Comment: Logcat errors have been aadded. Thank you again and I apologize for the large font size. Not sure how to make it back to a smaller font.

Comment: It's NetworkOnMainThread exception, use AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it because I'm not implementing Async Task?

Yes. Look at the LogCat and find the lowest "Caused by", in this case it's a NetworkOnMainThreadException. The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) reads:

> The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread. ... See the document [Designing for Responsiveness](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html).

If we read from the bottom of the LogCat upwards, you'll see that your last run code and the line above it is:

```
    at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:732)
    at com.sara.facebookappl.MainActivity.updateButtonImage(MainActivity.java:83)
```

Line 83 calls `Facebook#request()` which is a Network operation... Create a custom AsyncTask then move this line and all of it's supporting code into it's `doInBackground()` method:

```
JSONObject obj=null;
URL img_url =null;

try {
    String jsonUser= fb.request("me");
    obj = Util.parseJson(jsonUser);
    String id = obj.optString("id"); 
    String name = obj.optString("name");
}catch (FacebookError e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

*Except* the line `welcome.setText("Welcome, " + name);`. You cannot access UI objects, like TextViews, in `doInBackground()`. You need to put this code in `onPostExecute()`, if you read the AsyncTask documentation you'll learn it does have access to the UI Thread.

It sounds complicated, but after some reading and a few tries, you'll discover that it's not that bad. There are numerous examples to help you if you get stuck. Good Luck!